What does "on" mean in "We'll go right on home"?
In the movie "Being There" (1979) there is a scene in which the main character gets into an accident. His leg gets trapped between the front of a parked car and the back of another that is backing out. He screams out in pain. A wealthy woman and her driver get out and offer him a trip to a hospital. During the ride, the woman changes her mind and says that she'll take the injured man home as her husband is sick and there are doctors present in her home. She says to the driver.

David, We'll go right on home

I'm pretty sure that "right" is an adverb here, which means:
: without delay: immediately
right after lunch (Merriam Webster)
Is "on" also an adverb that means...
a
: forward or at a more advanced point in space or time
went on home
later on (Merriam Webster)
...?
The sentence "David, We'll go immediately forward home" doesn't sound too natural to me, though.

The standard way to say it would be "We'll go straight home". Right on is a colloquialism which doesn't need detailed analysis.

"on" can have the meaning "continuing in the direction one is headed"

Go on, keep walking. You'll see the beehive up in the tree in another few feet. That big lower limb is blocking your view.

In "right on home" the direction is "homeward" so "on" there has the sense of "not making any side-trips or stopping to do any errands while on our way home".

Is this a correct definition for the sense you are talking about:" 21. in a direction towards something, esp forwards; so as to make progress: we drove on towards London; march on!."?

@StaticBounce  Yes.  "forwards" is another way of saying "in the direction one is headed". I don't think "towards something" should be included in the definition, BTW. You could be lost in the middle of the desert and "trudge on" and not be going "towards something"

I knew about the sense "continuing in the direction one is headed" but this one seems to be describing "the act of continuing any action" as in "I will work on till I'm finished" but some dictionaries distinguish between two different senses, like dictionary.com:

forward, onward, or along, as in any course or process:
further on.
with continuous activity:
to work on.


The adverb is “right on”.  It’s very informal (and regional) but it effectively means something like “starting immediately and continuing briskly”.
“Y’all can just get right on out of here.”

OR... "Y’all can just get straight {on} outta here!"

Just to be clear, "right on home" is not a southernism, y'all.

@FumbleFingers — OR... “second star to the right and straight on till morning”.

@Michael Lorton It must be very informal. There isn't a single entry in any of the dictionaries I use (including the Green’s Dictionary of Slang) that contains this defintion.
